# How do I make my checkbox filter inclusive, rather than exclusive

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

At the moment, this code is doing half of what I want - it's filtering the data. Unfortunately, it's doing the opposite of what I am attempting to do.

For example, when you click the checkbox, it'll add a new filter to the filter array, and only display the cards that contain everything within that filter array. So if you were to click the 'Green' checkbox, only cards with 'G' in their colors array will be displayed. If you click 'Black' afterwards, only cards with 'G' AND 'B' in their colors array will show

The behavior I am looking for is the opposite. I'd like to start the page with:

```
filterOptions: [
    {checked: true, value: "W", name: "White"},
    {checked: true, value: "U", name: "Blue"},
    {checked: true, value: "B", name: "Black"},
    {checked: true, value: "R", name: "Red"},
    {checked: true, value: "G", name: "Green"},
    {checked: true, value: "KLD", name: "Kaladesh"},
]
```

And I'd like this behavior to show all of the cards. Once the checkbox is clicked and 'checked' becomes false, it will filter out the cards that contain that data.

I believe the function that needs to be modified is:

```
if (this.selectedFilters.length > 0) {
    filteredDataByFilters = Object.values(this.filteredData).filter(obj =>
    this.selectedFilters.every(val => obj.colors.indexOf(val) >= 0));
    this.filteredData = filteredDataByFilters;
}
```

Below is a snippet that shows what I am currently working with.

```js
const cards = [
    {
        "Sluiceway Scorpion": {
            "colorIdentity": [
                "B",
                "G"
            ],
            "colors": [
                "B",
                "G"
            ],
            "convertedManaCost": 4.0,
            "isReserved": false,
            "layout": "normal",
            "legalities": {
                "1v1": "Legal",
                "commander": "Legal",
                "duel": "Legal",
                "legacy": "Legal",
                "modern": "Legal",
                "pauper": "Legal",
                "penny": "Legal",
                "vintage": "Legal"
            },
            "manaCost": "{2}{B}{G}",
            "name": "Sluiceway Scorpion",
            "power": "2",
            "printings": [
                "RTR"
            ],
            "rulings": [
                {
                    "date": "2013-04-15",
                    "text": "Exiling the creature card with scavenge is part of the cost of activating the scavenge ability. Once the ability is activated and the cost is paid, it’s too late to stop the ability from being activated by trying to remove the creature card from the graveyard."
                }
            ],
            "subtypes": [
                "Scorpion"
            ],
            "supertypes": [],
            "text": "Deathtouch (Any amount of damage this deals to a creature is enough to destroy it.)\nScavenge {1}{B}{G} ({1}{B}{G}, Exile this card from your graveyard: Put a number of +1/+1 counters equal to this card's power on target creature. Scavenge only as a sorcery.)",
            "toughness": "2",
            "type": "Creature — Scorpion",
            "types": [
                "Creature"
            ],
            "uuid": "7b6dbadf-a6f7-4876-9c3f-44e4a33b2bee"
        },
        "Tezzeret the Seeker": {
        "colorIdentity": [
            "U"
        ],
        "colors": [
            "U"
        ],
        "convertedManaCost": 5.0,
        "isReserved": false,
        "layout": "normal",
        "legalities": {
            "1v1": "Legal",
            "commander": "Legal",
            "duel": "Legal",
            "legacy": "Legal",
            "modern": "Legal",
            "vintage": "Legal"
        },
        "loyalty": "4",
        "manaCost": "{3}{U}{U}",
        "name": "Tezzeret the Seeker",
        "printings": [
            "ALA",
            "DDF",
            "MM2"
        ],
        "rulings": [{
                "date": "2008-10-01",
                "text": "The first ability can target zero, one, or two artifacts. You may activate it with no targets just to put a loyalty counter on Tezzeret."
            },
            {
                "date": "2008-10-01",
                "text": "For the second ability, you choose the value of X when you activate it. You don’t look through your library until the ability resolves. (In other words, you can’t look through your library, decide what artifact card you want, and then determine what X is.) You can’t choose an X that’s greater than the number of loyalty counters on Tezzeret."
            },
            {
                "date": "2008-10-01",
                "text": "The third ability affects all artifacts you control, including artifacts that are already creatures."
            },
            {
                "date": "2008-10-01",
                "text": "The third ability causes artifacts you control to become creatures in addition to their other card types."
            },
            {
                "date": "2009-10-01",
                "text": "A noncreature permanent that turns into a creature is subject to the “summoning sickness” rule: It can only attack, and its {T} abilities can only be activated, if its controller has continuously controlled that permanent since the beginning of their most recent turn."
            },
            {
                "date": "2009-10-01",
                "text": "The effect from the ability overwrites other effects that set power and/or toughness if and only if those effects existed before the ability resolved. It will not overwrite effects that modify power or toughness (whether from a static ability, counters, or a resolved spell or ability), nor will it overwrite effects that set power and toughness which come into existence after the ability resolves. Effects that switch the creature’s power and toughness are always applied after any other power or toughness changing effects, including this one, regardless of the order in which they are created."
            }
        ],
        "starter": true,
        "subtypes": [
            "Tezzeret"
        ],
        "supertypes": [
            "Legendary"
        ],
        "text": "+1: Untap up to two target artifacts.\n−X: Search your library for an artifact card with converted mana cost X or less and put it onto the battlefield. Then shuffle your library.\n−5: Artifacts you control become artifact creatures with base power and toughness 5/5 until end of turn.",
        "type": "Legendary Planeswalker — Tezzeret",
        "types": [
            "Planeswalker"
        ],
        "uuid": "e5250db5-6dfc-46ef-a6f7-198a3e0594cc"
    },
    }
];


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    selectedFilters: function() {
        let filters = [];
        let checkedFilters = this.filterOptions.filter(obj => obj.checked);
        checkedFilters.forEach(element => {
        filters.push(element.value);
        });
        return filters;
    }
  },
    data: function() {
        return {
            filteredData: [],
            search: "", 
            filterOptions: [
                {checked: false, value: "W", name: "White"},
                {checked: false, value: "U", name: "Blue"},
                {checked: false, value: "B", name: "Black"},
                {checked: false, value: "R", name: "Red"},
                {checked: false, value: "G", name: "Green"},
                {checked: false, value: "KLD", name: "Kaladesh"},
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getFilteredData: function(){
            this.filteredData = cards[0];
            let filteredDataByFilters = [];
            let filteredDataBySearch = [];
            
            if (this.selectedFilters.length > 0) {
                filteredDataByFilters = Object.values(this.filteredData).filter(obj =>
                this.selectedFilters.every(val => obj.colors.indexOf(val) >= 0)
                );
                this.filteredData = filteredDataByFilters;
            }

            // set filters
            // if (this.selectedFilters.length > 0) {
            //     filteredDataByFilters = Object.values(this.filteredData).filter(obj =>
            //     this.selectedFilters.every(val => obj.printings.indexOf(val) >= 0)
            //     );
            //     this.filteredData = filteredDataByFilters;
            // }

            if (this.search !== "") {
                filteredDataBySearch = Object.values(this.filteredData).filter(obj => 
                obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
                this.filteredData = filteredDataBySearch;
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getFilteredData();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
      <!-- the search bar form -->
      <form v-on:submit="getFilteredData">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-10">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter key word  ..."
              v-model="search"
              v-on:keyup="getFilteredData"
            >
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- check boxes -->
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <div v-for="(filter, index) in filterOptions" :key="index" class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            v-model="filter.checked"
            v-on:change="getFilteredData"
          >
          <label class="form-check-label">{{ filter.name }}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- end of checkboxes -->
        <div class="cards-go-here">
            <div v-for="(card, index) in filteredData" :key="index">{{card.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to change the every in your function to a some?

Comment: That was it. Thank you @bronkula

Comment: Nice catch @bronkula! BTW, looks like a nice game too @Bonteq. Will this be available for playing somewhere? :P The card descriptions are very intriguing!

Comment: Hey @jom! I'm building a web app using data from the card game Magic the Gathering. If you're interested, they have physical cards as well as a new online game called Magic the Gathering: Arena. It is a blast!!!

Comment: @Bonteq Nice! Checking now ;)